# how to get only month and year in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

im newbie in query and i want to extract only month and year so how do i do that, i tried using date_part but its only extract month

```
select 
case when 
date_part('day', now()) >=25 then date_part('month', now())
else date_part('month', now())-1 end
```

can anyone help me

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a specification of *what* month and year.

Answer (score 2):

Your query works perfectly.
Please see [this demo:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/2501)

---

Today is `2017-08-12` and the query gives `8-1` = `7` as expected

```
select 
case when date_part('day', now()) >=25 
     then date_part('month', now())
     else date_part('month', now())-1 
end
;

| case |
|------|
|    7 |
```

---

Another two cases work fine too:

```
select 
case when date_part('day', date '2017-08-12') >=25 
     then date_part('month', date '2017-08-12')
     else date_part('month', date '2017-08-12')-1 
end
;
| case |
|------|
|    7 |
```

---

```
select 
case when date_part('day', date '2017-08-26') >=25 
     then date_part('month', date '2017-08-26')
     else date_part('month', date '2017-08-26')-1 
end
;
| case |
|------|
|    8 |
```

Comment: my querry only shows month, what if i want to extract month and year too, how do i do that sir?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what is a desired result you want, but to extract year/month/anything else from date you can use TO_CHAR function.

For example:

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY'), to_char(current_timestamp, 'MONTH');

select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM');
```

To add minutes/hours/days/months/years whatever to a date use **interval** operator just like this:

```
select to_char(now() + interval '1' month, 'YYYY-MM');
```

You can add many intervals at once:

```
select to_char(now() + interval '1' month + interval '-1' year, 'YYYY-MM');
```

[Here are all template patterns for Date/Time Formatting.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

Comment: my result from querry above only shows month but i want to show month and year also sir

Comment: Do you want a month and a year within single column? Just use a different pattern: select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') or select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MONTH').

Comment: yea thats what im trying to achieve but why cant i get a result from select to_char(now(), 'day')-1 ?

Comment: Because it's a string value. To add a minute/hour/day/month/year/whatever use INTERVAL statement like select to_char(now() + interval '1' month, 'YYYY-MONTH'); It will get current time plus one month.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXTRACT` function to extract month, year and day from `DATE`.

Below is the query using which you can achieve what you posted in question.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN (extract(DAY
                         FROM CURRENT_DATE) >= 25) THEN (extract(MONTH
                                                                 FROM CURRENT_DATE))
           ELSE (extract(MONTH
                         FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1)
       END;
```

**Result:**

[image]

As today is 12th day of the month, it returns 7 (previous month). You can check DEMO [here](http://rextester.com/OGAOR63243)

**Edit**:

If you want to extract month and year both, extract it separately and concatenate it.
Below is the updated query.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN (extract(DAY
                         FROM CURRENT_DATE) >= 25) THEN (extract(MONTH
                                                                 FROM CURRENT_DATE) || ', ' || extract(Year FROM CURRENT_DATE))
           ELSE (extract(MONTH
                         FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1 || ', ' || extract(Year FROM CURRENT_DATE))
       END;
```

Check demo [here](http://rextester.com/RPE11228)

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can get a numeric representation in a string by using:

```
   select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY') as Year, to_char(current_timestamp, 'MONTH') as Month;
```